# SOCKS Proxy for ALL Web Traffic

Tags: linux, networking, ssh, proxy, putty

So I have a SSH Client and a SSH Server. I am to encrypt web traffic(traffic to web server) via Firefox Socks proxy. Right now it seems like encrypting internet traffic is application based only? Example, config firefox,ie,etc.

Is the above question true? If not is there a Windows application that allows encrypted internet traffic WITHOUT configuring browser specific applications?

How about Linux wise? Eventually I want to take this to a Ubuntu computer (ssh client) that is connected to a ssh server and use sock proxy.

Comment: I see putty(my ssh client) has a proxy configuration. However when I put my socks setting I did with firefox, the ssh session instantly closes.

Comment: Ideally I would like to use my dd-wrt router to redirect http, https traffic to my raspberry pi (raspbain) that is connected to my ssh server (digital ocean). I know, from the server the traffic is wide open, but thats not the focus of my project yet! This is why I am trying to do the above and where VPN might work, ideally its a over kill.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOCKS proxy is proxy on application level. There is settings in `NetworkManager` in Ubuntu, where you can define the SOCKS address and port (there will be probably some in network settings in windows), similar as you did it for Firefox, but it is up to the other applications if they respect system-wide proxy configuration or not. They can simply "go outside" to the internet directly. I believe most of the simpler apps will ignore it.

If you want to encrypt *all* traffic point-to-point, you should look for VPN. There is also basic VPN in openssh itself, but setting up VPN is over the extent of this answer.

Comment: Ya I found a site that talks about VPN over ssh: http://sleepyhead.de/howto/?href=vpn. I am a little worried about vpn over ssh performance. My issue with VPN in general is that I only want port 80,8080,443("Web Traffic") and not other traffic.I think I am going to rephrase the title of the post.